# Ensuring Docker container will start automatically when host starts

Tags: docker

Is there a way to start a Docker container automatically when the host starts? Before, I use the ‘—restart always’ parameter with docker run but it only works if Docker Engine is not killed.

Comment: if you're using a RHEL variant, this should work: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#start-automatically-at-system-boot

Comment: I made this as my reference but when I try starting the service, it always fails and I don’t get a clear error. http://container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd/

Comment: Why don't you want to use `--restart always`? With the flag, the container will start automatically every time the host starts before you `delete` the container.

Comment: @SangminKim The behavior actually is that if the host dies, the container does not start back up. I’ll have a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment, I think you have misunderstood about `--restart always`.

Once `docker run --restart always container` is run, the `container` is restarted every time the host is restarted even though you stop the `container` explicitly .

For example.

```
$ docker run --restart always --detach --name auto-start-redis redis
d04dfbd73eb9d2ba5beac41363aa5c45c0e034e08173daa6146c3c704e0cd1da
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d04dfbd73eb9        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   4 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        6379/tcp            auto-start-redis
$ reboot       

# After reboot-------------------------------

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d04dfbd73eb9        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   About a minute ago   Up 21 seconds       6379/tcp            auto-start-redis

$ docker stop auto-start-redis
auto-start-redis
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
d04dfbd73eb9        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   2 minutes ago       Exited (0) 30 seconds ago                       auto-start-redis
$ reboot 

# After reboot-------------------------------

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d04dfbd73eb9        redis               "docker-entrypoint..."   3 minutes ago       Up 12 seconds       6379/tcp            auto-start-redis
```

However, of course, it is based upon a premise that `docker-host` is auto-started. `docker-host` in here means `docker daemon` process itself. Usually `docker-host` will auto-start by default but if it is not, you need to set it yourself.

I am not sure which OS you are using but when it comes to `Ubuntu16`, you can make it with `systemctl` command.

```
$ sudo systemctl enable docker  
# To tell systemd to start services automatically at boot, you must enable.
```

Comment: I’ll have a look again. I used the restart always parameter but for some reason it doesn’t start although before I had no problems.

Comment: If you want to start the docker daemon and docker desktop automatically on windows start-up follow these steps https://thecodeframework.com/start-docker-desktop-on-windows-start-up-without-user-logon/

Answer (score 0):

If you use docker swarm, you can make [global service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/#replicated-and-global-services) with `--mode global` flag that ensures run on every node in docker swarm.

```
docker service create --mode global ...
```

If you don't use docker swarm, the best solution I think is to use init system of your system like `systemd` as @I.R.R said. You can make your own `service` file for systemd and specify the condition when the service starts like below.

```
[Unit]
Description=Your App
After=docker
```

Refer to this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) by digital ocean.

Comment: Docker swarm in this case is an overkill. I actually tried doing the service route but for some reason, it always fails. What I do is to have a docker start command in the file.